# Show this assertion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I am stuck on the following task:

Fix a vector $y \in C^n$ and let $f(x,y)$ be a function defined on $C^n \times C^n$ such that $f(0,y)=1$ and its $n$th partial derivative on $x$ satisfies $\frac{\partial^n{f}(0,y)}{\partial{x}^n}=1.$  Show that $f$ has an expension  entiere series on $x$.
In addition,   have we the following $$\parallel f(x,y)\parallel \leq \exp(\parallel x \parallel \times \parallel y \parallel)$$?

Any help please and thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Note $g_y(x)=f(x,y)$. Then bound the difference $$g_y(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{g_y^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n = g_y(x)-f(0,y)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(xy)^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Using Taylor's theorem aroung $0$, in fact, I assume that the function $h(x)=f(x,y)$ is differentiable at every point $x$ because $n$th derivative on $x$ is equal to $y^nf(x,y)$ and $f(0,y)=1$, then $$h(x)=\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{h^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n =\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{y^{n}f(0,y)}{n!}x^n .$$
For other hand, assuming $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0,y)}{n!}$, is not easy to prove  $||\sum a_n x^n || < \sum ||a_nx^n||$ because $f^{(n)}(0,y)$ is not a number, it is in a Dual space, really, we have that $$\begin{array}{ccc}
f^{(n)}(0,y)\in & \underbrace{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{2},\cdots,\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{2}} & ,\mathbb{R})\cdots)).\\
 & n-\mbox{times}
\end{array}$$
Note that $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2},\cdots\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathbb{R}\right)\cdots\right)\right)$ and $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right)$ are homeomorphic, this homeomorphism is linear and isometry.

**Remark**: I assume that the function $f$ is of real value.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding why the OP writes $||a_nx^n||$ with the $a_n$ specified, since $a_n$ looks real (assuming the $f^{(n)}$ are derivatives in $x$), $x$ is real, and so the "norms" should be absolute values.  I also fail to see how the inequality can be true if all $f^{(n)}(0,y)$ are positive, which they are if $y$ is positive.

Comment: If the $f^{(n)}$ are as the answer now says, derivatives in $(x,y)$ rather than in $x$, each in a different dual space depending on $n$, how would one even make sense of the sum $\sum a_n x^n=\sum f^{(n)}x^n/n!$?  To make sense of the sum, one would have to immerse all of those dual spaces in one big happy dual space containing all of them, it seems to me naively.

Comment: @ForgotALot You are right, I think the problem could be meaningless, for example, this sum is meaningless when $f\left(x,y\right)=e^{xy}$.